# Wrong monero wallet adress (claymore, nanopool)

Tags: mining-pool-setup, bittrex

I wonder what I'm doing wrong when I try to mine monero with claymore and nanopool. See pic below.

I've written in my base adress and my payment id. Is there something I do not understand?

[image]

Comment: Is that your own address or an exchange's address?

Comment: It's the address to my exchange account.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have also updated the **epools.txt** file with your address details. This resolved the error for me.